# Regex to verify Succesive Repetition of Characters in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net, character, repeat

I am looking for a regular expression in VB.Net that will match the text on these conditions:

- **First condition:** If the word is two characters, make sure the two characters are unique.

  Example: **ab** is accepted not  **aa** or **bb**.
- **Second condition:** If the word contains more than two characters, I want to make sure the same character doesn't appear three (or more) times in a row.

  Example: **aabaa** and **abbaa** are accepted, but not **aaabb**, **abbbaa**, **xxyyyy** (because the same character is repeated three or more times successively).

Comment: I wasn't sure if the context relates to matching the whole string, but that's the way I answered. If you just want this to pertain to the words _within_ the string, @cfqueryparam answer is great.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I realized I made a mistake in reading your question

You want to bar words longer than 2 letters from having 3 of the same character **in a row**.

This ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT4zV7/1)) will work:

```
\b(?!\w*(\w)\1\1\w*|(\w)\2)\w*\b
```

And, as below, you can inverse the results by changing the first `!` to `=`.

```
\b(?=\w*(\w)\1\1\w*|(\w)\2)\w*\b
```

---

(old answer below)

This ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO4pL8/2)) should work for you

```
\b(?!(?=\w{3,})\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*\1\w*|(?=\w{2})(\w)(?=\2))\w{2,}\b
```

If you want to inverse the results, as seen in the demo, simply change the very first `!` to `=`:

```
\b(?=(?=\w{3,})\w*(\w)\w*\1\w*\1\w*|(?=\w{2})(\w)(?=\2))\w{2,}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition 1 is done with an initial assertion check at the beginning.
Condition 2 is satisfied with an assertion check as each character is
matched.

This assumes all characters, not just alpha.

```
 # (?s)^(?!(.)\1$)(?:(.)(?!\2{2}))+$

 (?s)                # Modifier, dot-all     
 ^                   # BOS
                     # Condition 1: Assert not dup char
                     # on 2 char strings
 (?!
      ( . )          # (1)
      \1 $ 
 )
                     # Match the string
 (?:
      ( . )          # (2)
      (?! \2{2} )    # Condition 2: Assert not same chars
                     # 3 or more times in a row
 )+
 $                   # EOS
```

This discriminates between Alpha / Non-alpha

```
 # (?i)^(?!([a-z])\1$)(?:([a-z])(?!\2{2})|[^a-z])+$

 (?i)                 # Modifier, no case
 ^                    # BOS
 (?!                  # Assert -
      ( [a-z] )            # (1), Alpha
      \1 $                 # Condition 1:  not dup alpha on 2 char strings
 )
                      # Match the string
 (?:
      ( [a-z] )            # (2), Alpha
      (?! \2{2} )          # Condition 2: Assert - not same alpha 3 or more times in a row
   |                     # or,
      [^a-z]               # Non-alpha
 )+
 $                    # EOS
```

Comment: sln, your code works but it also accepts a text composed of single character. I want the text to be at least two characters. how to modify the code to accept only two characters at least.

Comment: @midomar - That's not a condition you've listed. Usually though, a simple `^(?=..)`  works.